# How to rewrite some lines from files on AIX?

Tags: bash, sed, ksh, aix

I've many files like :

```
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;512.00;295.16;/opt/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;128.00;106.54;/var/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;256.00;180.79;/usr/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;384.00;191.13;/var/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;256.00;255.37;/var/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;3200.00;2679.36;/var/opt/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;256.00;255.07;/var/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;64.00;62.67;/etc/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;1664.00;1163.33;/opt
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;256.00;146.13;/opt/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;2176.00;952.90;/opt/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;22784.00;10353.91;/opt/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;256.00;253.64;/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;229.92;/home
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;1024.00;556.73;/opt
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;180.79;/usr/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;384.00;190.90;/var
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;255.37;/var/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;128.00;127.63;/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;76.86;/opt/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;2176.00;1682.93;/opt/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;145.66;/opt/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;2176.00;952.90;/opt/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;22784.00;10421.72;/opt/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;253.64;/
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;1024.00;138.8;/
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;5248.00;4230.34;/usr
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;2560.00;499.37;/var
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;3584.00;67.79;/tmp
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;256.00;25.9;/home
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;1024.00;467.27;/opt
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;384.00;0.38;/usr/
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;256.00;21.36;/
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;512.00;216.84;/opt/
```

I would like to substract the $3 and $4 field to the begin of the file to the last line including the pattern " 2019-10-29-12-00 ". Someone from this site give me this command :

```
sed '/2019-10-29-12-00/{:a;n;//ba;Q}' file.txt
```

And I'm able to do what I want if I add`awk -F';' '{print $1";"$2";"$3";"($3 - $4)";"$5}'` to this sed command...

I'm able to rewrite with linux and the `-i` flag for sed, but this flag doesn't exist on AIX... So How I can rewrite all the lines from the begin to the last lines with the pattern "2019-10-29-12-00" without delete the rest of the lines ?

Comment: `sed .... file.txt > tempfile` `mv tempfile file.txt` ?

Comment: The problem with my command is that I rewrite the lines that I need, but I create a new file only with the lines modified, not with all the lines ( lines modified + the rest )

Comment: Your comment is still unclear (to me, anyway), Do you want to keep all lines of data or not? OR do you want a separate new file with just the subset, OR do you want to replace existing file with just the subset of data? @KamilCuk 's solution gives you the last .In any case, given AIX and your locked down environment, you'll have to manage your files with an extra 1-4 lines of code, rather than just `sed -i`. One very slight enhancement to above would be `sed ... file txt.>tmpfile && mv tmpfile file.txt` so that the `mv` is only executed if there are no errors running `sed`. Good luck.

Comment: I want to keep all my lines AND just modify the line ( to the beginning at the last line with my pattern 2019-10-29-12-00 ) with my command awk -F';' '{print $1";"$2";"$3";"($3 - $4)";"$5}'.

Comment: @OP: What is it look like when you _add this awk-command to that sed-command?_

Answer (score 0):

With awk you can do it on this way

```
awk -F';' '{if ($1=="2019-10-29-12-00")  print $1";"$2";"$3";"($3 - $4)";"$5; else print}' input_file >output
mv output input_file
```